# Bugzilla 5.0.4 doesn't recognize Apache2::SizeLimit 0.97

Tags: perl

I'm upgrading Bugzilla from 4.2.1 to 5.0.4 on Centos 6.9

The 'checksetup.pl' says I'm missing optional module Apache2::SizeLimit v 0.96, but when I do:

```
/usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Apache2::SizeLimit
```

It tells me

> Installing Apache2::SizeLimit version 0.96...
>
> Apache2::SizeLimit is up to date (0.97).

So, it seems checksetup.pl doesn't recognise that 0.97 is already installed.

It doesn't seem like theres an easy process to downgrade this module.  Is there another way to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem stems from the module existing in two distributions: [mod_perl2](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/mod_perl/docs/api/Apache2/SizeLimit.pod) and [Apache-SizeLimit](https://metacpan.org/pod/Apache::SizeLimit). Qualify the distro name to resolve to the dist with the higher version number:

```
cpan PHRED/Apache-SizeLimit-0.97.tar.gz
cpanm PHRED/Apache-SizeLimit-0.97.tar.gz
```

Unfortunately, `…/perl install-module.pl` is not able to resolve a qualified name, so you need to use `cpan` or `cpanm` or the like.

Please report these bugs at bugzilla.

Comment: I'm not sure I followed these instructions properly.  I tried issuing the first command, and it did a bunch of stuff, but the problem remains.  Could you add more info?

Comment: [Open a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and show the details of "bunch of stuff".

Answer (score 0):

Bugzilla project admin here. install-module.pl is hot garbage, but the real issue here is that you can't really (easily) get a working mod_perl installed from cpan.

The correct-ish thing at the moment is use the distro's package manager to install mod_perl.

Answer (score 0):

I found answers with the help of a Bugzilla dev, I needed to do

```
curl -L https://cpanmin.us > /usr/local/bin/cpanm
chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/cpanm
```

to install cpanm, then

```
cpanm --installdeps --notest --with-recommends .
yum install mod_perl-devel
cpanm --notest Apache2::SizeLimit
```

after which `./checksetup` resolved the 0.96 version of SizeLimit